# using strtotime with next Wednesday 20:16

Tags: php, strtotime

My time is in 24 hour format

I am trying to use `strtotime` as

```
$final_date = strtotime("next Wednesday 20:16")
```

but when I echo

```
echo date("D, d M, Y H:s A", $final_date)
```

I get

```
Wed, 07 Mar, 2018 20:00
```

The minutes are not accounted for, but the hour works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `H:i A`. You are echoing seconds (while you didn't set it previously), not minutes.

Comment: OMG I feel like an idiot....gees thanks man

Comment: @Phil make it an answer so I can mark it since you were first

Comment: I spent so much time racking my brain and it was in front of my face...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo date("D, d M, Y H:i A", $final_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` is seconds, `i` is minutes

```
echo date("D, d M, Y H:i A", $final_date);
```